# PayPal adaptive guest payment requirements

Tags: paypal, credit-card, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are using the adaptive payment API to setup a payment between 2 of our users. The receiver user has a paypal account, the source (the one who pays) doesn't. We don't use any chained or parallel payments just simple tranffer from A to B.
We'd like to allow the source to pay with credit/debit card. The problem is that in some cases its allowed, and in some it isn't.

We found [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/ap-guest-payments/) document about the subject but it looks outdated, since in the limitations section it says:

> Cannot be made to a personal or un-registered PayPal account

I have a personal account and it works with that but with my colleague's personal account (different country) it doesn't.

> Not available if the API caller passes an email address in the request
>   envelope.

This is very vague. Pass where? We use the email address in the pay request but it works in some cases.

Could anyone give some up-to-date info about this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my findings together with PP_MSI_Colin's answer:

**Documentations**

[Guest payment - integration guide (UI is different now)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#guest-payments)

[Guest payment - adaptive payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/ap-guest-payments/)

[Account optional settings](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional)

**Requirements**

- Upgrade to business or premium account.
- Make sure the email address is verified.
- Make sure that on [this settings page](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional) the Paypal account optional setting is ON.

**Limitations, exceptions**

- In EU, this option is limited to 10 payments/card
- In some countries (tested in Hungary) a personal account can also receive guest payments.
- In some countries it is always disabled. No official list found.

**Logic**

Even if it is enabled for a user, it is up to Paypal if they show it or not.  Where its enabled it also depends on the paying user. If Paypal finds (from cookies, etc) that the user has a paypal account they don't show credit card option. To test it try to pay in an incognito window. PayPal’s fraud prevention measures can also cause the guest checkout to not be displayed in certain scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Guest payments are only made available to certain countries no matter which PayPal product you are using (PayPal Payments Standard, PayPal Express Checkout, Adaptive Payments). So if a buyer is in a country that requires a PayPal account, then they will only see the option to "Login to PayPal" or "Create Account" when they land of the PayPal checkout page. Unfortunately there is not a list of countires in our documentation to show which countries allow guest payments and which don't.

Comment: Thanks, could you point me to some more details about this? Is this documented somewhere? Which countries are supported? Any other constraints? Its really frustrating that we cannot even tell our users what are the rules.

Comment: The only documentation available is this link and it is very limited information: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional
Another factor is that PayPal’s fraud prevention measures can also cause the guest checkout to not be displayed in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Limitations for making guest payments via PayPal adaptive payments are documented here:

[image]

`Guest payments cannot be made to a personal or un-registered PayPal account`